# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I am getting the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary 
FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) 
on port 7055; process output follows:
```

I am using Firefox version 40.0.3 & Eclipse version Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2).

The strange thing is, the script ran successfully 2 times in between. But, failing after that continuously.

Comment: Which error thrown? What is your windows version?

Answer (score -1):

To get better help, please post the full stack of the exception if possible.

- check the location on you computer if the firefox.exe exist in the specified location.
- check the window registery ( regedit) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Softwar/Mozilla/Mozilla Firefore xx.x.x/bin`   double click PathToExe to find if the path exist there
- add the firefox.exe which exist on your computer after check ( the full path)
  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe` into the environment variable Path

Do each of the above  check and see if it works.

If it does not work, try to install the firefox again on your computer